# How can i get the attribute value of HtmlGenericControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, htmlgenericcontrol

I create `HtmlGenericControl` like this :

```
HtmlGenericControl inner_li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
inner_li.Attributes.Add("style", "list-style-type: none");
```

---

How can i get the value of this attribue(`style`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it using indexer:

```
var style = inner_li.Attributes["style"];
```

Just a side note: when dealing with styles it's better to use [`HtmlControl.Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d53fws1t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property:

```
inner_li.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.ListStyleType] = "none";
```

Answer (score 2):

The Attributes property is name value collection. So you can do 
`string tempstr = inner_li.Attributes["style"]`.

See the [msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.attributes.aspx#Y308).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value using the below statement

```
string myvalue= inner_li.Attributes["style"];
```