# Copy css from one control to another control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have multiple image control on aspx page. I am assigning some css as follows

```
control1.Style.Add("position", "relative");
...
...
```

depending on some calculation.

Now what I want is to copy the same style on other control  say `control2`

```
//something like 
control2.Style=control1.Style;
//not possible since it has no setter
```

So is there is another way of doing this like if I say

```
 control2=control1;
```

will it copy all the property inside control1 to control 2. I don't think it is possible.
So is there any way of doing this.

### Edit 1

When I write

```
control2=control1;
```

All the css is copied from control1 to control2 (in my case both are of same type). But weather it is going to change something else?

Comment: can' you use a css class selector and assign this to your controls?

Comment: It's better you write an css class and assign to control instead of individual style.

Comment: @VDesign do you want to say `control1.Attributes.Add("Style","values")`

Comment: @RachitPatel the values get from calculation so css classes can't be used.

Comment: ok, I think you get style using control1.Attributes.Add("Style","values") but I suggest you can get same thing very easily through Jquery.

Comment: var style = inner_li.Attributes["style"];

Comment: @RachitPatel It's not a good idea to suggest a Javascript library (or even Vanilla) when the OP clearly is asking about server-side code.

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496037/how-can-i-get-the-attribute-value-of-htmlgenericcontrol

Comment: @MelanciaUK I am just suggesting that it's easily achievable through jqery. May be it would be help him

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a direct way to do this. But you can create an extension method like this.

```
public static class StyleExtension 
{
    public static void AddExisting(this CssStyleCollection collection, 
        CssStyleCollection existing)
    {
        foreach (string item in existing.Keys)
        {
            collection.Add(item, existing[item]);
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this.

```
cmdSubmit.Style.Add("Color", "Red");
cmdSubmit.Style.Add("FontSize", "20");

Button1.Style.AddExisting(cmdSubmit.Style);
```

Answer (score 0):

your question was answered on some forum [HERE](http://forums.asp.net/t/617980.aspx) 
they have wrote a function to clone controls.

to comply with stackoverflow's rules, i add the code from that answer below:

```
/// <summary>
/// The ControlCloneEngine creates copies of ASP.NET controls
/// </summary>
public class ControlCloneEngine
{
    private int m_instanceCount;
    public ControlCloneEngine()
    {
        m_instanceCount = 1;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Clone a control.  Call this function in Page_Init
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ctrlSource">The control to clone</param>
    /// <returns>a new copy of the control</returns>
    public Control Copy(Control ctrlSource)
    {
        Type t = ctrlSource.GetType();
        Control ctrlDest = (Control)t.InvokeMember("", BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, null);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in t.GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.CanWrite)
            {
                if (prop.Name == "ID")
                {
                    ctrlDest.ID = ctrlSource.ID + "c" + m_instanceCount;
                }
                else
                {
                    prop.SetValue(ctrlDest, prop.GetValue(ctrlSource, null), null);
                }
            }
        }
        m_instanceCount++;
        return ctrlDest;
    }
}
```